# cakephp sms functionality not working

Tags: cakephp, sms, cakephp-1.3

```
$this->Email->to = '+91number@airtelmail.com';
$this->Email->subject = 'hi';
$this->Email->from = emailid;
$this->Email->template = null;       
$this->Email->sendAs = 'text';
$text = "Device is down";
$this->Email->send($text);
```

With Above code, if I set  `$this->Email->sendAs = 'email';`, email can be sent, but it is not working for SMS?

Answer (score 2):

The sendAs property of the EmailComponent controls the format in which the e-mail is sent. That can be 'html', 'text' or 'both', which will send it as an HTML email with a plain text fallback.

So, I guess airtelmail will catch the emails sent to `<number>@airtelmail.com` and send them via SMS to `<number>`. However, that has nothing to do with the EmailComponent - the EmailComponent can only send emails.

You might wanna try to use a SMTP server for sending the mails out of your app - some providers classify emails sent by PHP as spam. See the [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1290/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP) for details.